# How to close a popup ad in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm writing a very light web scraper for a clothes website ("https://www.aeropostale.com/search/?q=shirt"), I'm trying to pull the price information, name of the product, and a link to the product page for each product. I've got that part down however I wanted to expand my code such that instead of getting the first 36 products (that's how much is listed before clicking show more) I want to eventually click show more to get the full list before doing the scraping. The problem I THINK is that when trying to do that the site pushes a site specific advertisement popup which keeps selenium from clicking on the show more button because the popup obscures the button itself.

I'm unsure how to use selenium to close this ad:[Ad in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rMwS.png)
Sometimes the ad is full page, sometimes it's small - don't think it matters because it seems to have the same id and parameters.

Below is my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



def gather():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get("https://www.aeropostale.com/search/?q=shirt")

    #current_url = driver.current_url

    driver.implicitly_wait(20)

    element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='closeIconContainer']"))
    element.click()
    """
    This section is for clicking load more until no longer possible
    while True:
        try:
            click_more = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "load-more-button").click()
            print("clicked once")
            driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            # Click the button while there is an option to load more
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break;
            
    """
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    ##This section prints the price of each entry on the page
    the_prices = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"product-pricing")
    for price in the_prices:
        print(price.get_attribute("innerText"))

    #The following code section finds all the Product links for the current page (The URLS)
    the_links = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"thumb-link")
    for link in the_links:
        print(link.get_attribute("href"))


    #This section of code prints ALL the product names on the CURRENT page
    product_name = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"product-name")
    for product in product_name:
        print(product.get_attribute("innerText"))


gather()
```

I thought the lines:

```
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='closeIconContainer']"))
element.click()
```

would locate the ad button and subsequently close it, but that didn't seem to be the case - using the xpath was the last thing I've tried, I have tried locating presence of element by the actual id before as well
which I thought was "closeIconContainer"

I've tried having the driver wait various amounts of time, but I think I might just be trying to close it wrong

It's also worth mentioning the ad comes up every time I run the program, but not when I specifically navigate to the url in my browser, I don't know if this has any bearing on anything but worth mentioning.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: `Selenium` runs fresh session - without `cookies`, history, etc. - and page doesn't know that you already visited and closed Ad. And when you run in browser then it remembers it. You should test page in `private mode` to see the same result as with `Selenium`. You may try to run `Selenium` with your `profile` to use your `cookies`.

Comment: maybe `Ad` is in `<iframe>` and then `Selenium` treats it as separated page and you have to use `switch_to.frame(...)` to access this elements. (And later you have to switch back to main window).

Comment: I visited page using `Firefox` and `Chromium` and I don't see any `advertisement popup`  - so I can't check what can make problems. maybe they display it only for some countries or in only some days. But I can't check it.

Comment: @furas Hey! Really appreciate the help, it was just as you said it was in an iframe, so I had to end up switching to it like you suggest ! Thank you so much!